# angular 2. Pipes. Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: angular, pipes-filters

i made a pipe

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'orgFilter'
})
export class OrgFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(orgs: Organization[], args: String[]): any {
        console.log(orgs)
       let filter = args[0].toLowerCase();
       return filter ? orgs.filter((org:Organization) => org.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) != -1): orgs;
}
```

and using it in html:

```
<tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="#organization of organizations | orgFilter:listFilter.value">
            <td>{{ organization.organizationName }}</td>
            <td>{{ organization.city }}</td>
            <td>{{ organization.state }}</td>
            <td>{{ organization.country }}</td>
            <td>
                <i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i>
            </td>
            <td>
                <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="col-md-4"><input type="text" #listFilter (keyup)="0" /></div>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

i am getting an error
browser_adapter.js:84 TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
at t.transform (orgFilter.ts:9)

where is the problem? does this mean that args doesn't have any values? am i using pipe wrong in html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the template you provided, it looks like instances of Organization have no member called "name", but a member called "organizationName" instead.

Maybe you can try replacing

```
org.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) != -1
```

with

```
org.organizationName.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) != -1
```

in your code.

**UPDATE**

That said, you can try a different way of binding you filter expression:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'orgFilter'
})
export class OrgFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(orgs: Organization[], expression:string): any {
       if(!expression){
            return orgs;
       }
       else {
            return orgs.filter((org:Organization) => org.organizationName.toLowerCase().indexOf(expression) != -1)
       }
}
```

Where expression refers to a member of your component, let's say:

```
filterExpression: string;
```

Then change your input text to:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filterExpression">
```

And change the pipe call to:

```
<tr *ngFor="#organization of organizations | orgFilter:filterExpression">
```

According to the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html) for a list filter you may have to declare your pipe as impure using:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'orgFilter',
  pure: false

})
```

Comment: i tried that, but it didn't work. the problem lies in let filter = args[0].toLowerCase(); does this mean that error is caused by args(which, if i understand it correctly, is a word i want to filter by) having no values? but it cant have values when i just opened the page. right?

Answer (score 0):

It's either going to be the `args` aren't defined or the `org.name` isn't defined.  You could try debugging it in the DevTools, maybe set the breakpoint at the start of the `transform()`